# Convert seconds to end to date format

Tags: python, time

SOAP client return seconds to end event.

How can I get from this seconds date in format "yyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss"

Answer (score 3):

A quick example (add 50000 seconds from *now* with [datetime.timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> time_event = time_now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=50000)
>>> time_event.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2010-05-08 12:07:05'
```